# How can I change the content of a TypeIt element in JS?

Tags: javascript, typeit

I am currently working with Typeit and I'm trying to update content after a button click, so that a new message appear in the same paragraph.

```
<p id="connection-typeit></p>
<button id="change-typeit"></button>
```

```
const mytypeit = new TypeIt("#connection-typeit", {
                                    strings: "One",
                                    speed: 100,
                                    waitUntilVisible: true,
                                }).go()

const button = document.getElementById("change-typeit")

button.addEventListener("onclick", () => {
    mytypeit.type("Two")
    mytypeit.go()
})
```

The problem is that when I click on the button this code, those two strings combine and the result is "OneTwo" instead of "Two".

How can I fix this?

I tried the `.destroy()` and `.reset()` methods, but those didn't work either.

Comment: I am concerned about the HTML you show. You missed a second quote mark after the end of the paragraph's ID. If that code is directly copied from your code, then I think I may have discovered your problem.

Comment: @Major_Flux-, thanks for pointing it out, I edited the post. However it isn't a direct copy of my code, which works fine ( the first TypeIt call works, "One" is being printed ). The problem is that when I call the .type function, it types "OneTwo", as if these two strings were concatenated, which obviously I'd want to avoid

Comment: In Java, when you use `System.out.print("String");` twice in a row, it comes out as `StringString`. Perhaps if you want a newline, you could have an additional `TypeIt.type("\n");` that occurs between them that could put them on a new line. You could also add the `\n` to the end of `One` or the beginning of `Two`.